# JavaScript: onchange function works in only 50% of cases

Tags: javascript, onchange

Let me preface this by saying that I don't often use JavaScript, so please excuse what is most likely a novice's simple misunderstanding.

I have a simple HTML form, which in part consists of a `select` drop down containing options `0` through `10`, followed by 10 replicated sets of `select` drop downs. The goal is to display only a certain number of the replicated drop down sets, based upon the user's selection in the first drop down. To do this, I've given each of the replicated sets of drop downs a unique ID, and the JavaScript toggles each one's `style.display` attribute each time the first `select` drop down is changed.

What I have works in an odd assortment of cases. For example, a change in selection from 4 to 5 works as expected, but 5 to 6 does not. 9 to 10 works, but 10 to 9 does not.

Interestingly, I discovered earlier that if the `for` loop that is run second in a `case` is longer than the first, that `case` doesn't execute properly -- previously, I had each `none` `for` loop running first in each `case` regardless of length, but have since switched those for `case`s greater than 5. Now the first selection always works, but subsequent user selection changes are oddly temperamental.

Here's my current code (sorry for inordinate length) :

```js
function kollege() {
switch (document.getElementById('college').value) {
  case '0':
    none = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      none[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    break;
  case '1':
    none = document.querySelectorAll('#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      none[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      inline[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    break;
  case '2':
    none = document.querySelectorAll('#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      none[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      inline[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    break;
  case '3':
    none = document.querySelectorAll('#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      none[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2,#c3');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      inline[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    break;
  case '4':
    none = document.querySelectorAll('#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      none[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      inline[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    break;
  case '5':
    none = document.querySelectorAll('#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      none[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      inline[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    break;
  case '6':
    inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      inline[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    none = document.querySelectorAll('#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      none[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    break;
  case '7':
    inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      inline[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    none = document.querySelectorAll('#c8,#c9,#c10');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      none[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    break;
  case '8':
    inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      inline[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    none = document.querySelectorAll('#c9,#c10');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      none[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    break;
  case '9':
    inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      inline[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    none = document.querySelectorAll('#c10');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      none[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    break;
  case '10':
    inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5,#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10');
    for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
      inline[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
    break;
}
}
```

```html
<form action="." method="POST">
  <label for="college">Number of Children who Require College Funding</label>
  <select name="college" id="college" onchange="kollege();">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  <div id="c1">
    <label for="type1">College Type</label>
    <select name="type1">
      <option value="26000">Private/Out-of-State Public</option>
      <option value="10000">Public In-State</option>
      <option value="3000">Community College</option>
    </select>
    <label for="coll1">Years of College</label>
    <select name="coll1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="c2">
    <label for="type2">College Type</label>
    <select name="type2">
      <option value="26000">Private/Out-of-State Public</option>
      <option value="10000">Public In-State</option>
      <option value="3000">Community College</option>
    </select>
    <label for="coll2">Years of College</label>
    <select name="coll2">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="c3">
    <label for="type3">College Type</label>
    <select name="type3">
      <option value="26000">Private/Out-of-State Public</option>
      <option value="10000">Public In-State</option>
      <option value="3000">Community College</option>
    </select>
    <label for="coll3">Years of College</label>
    <select name="coll3">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="c4">
    <label for="type4">College Type</label>
    <select name="type4">
      <option value="26000">Private/Out-of-State Public</option>
      <option value="10000">Public In-State</option>
      <option value="3000">Community College</option>
    </select>
    <label for="coll4">Years of College</label>
    <select name="coll4">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="c5">
    <label for="type5">College Type</label>
    <select name="type5">
      <option value="26000">Private/Out-of-State Public</option>
      <option value="10000">Public In-State</option>
      <option value="3000">Community College</option>
    </select>
    <label for="coll5">Years of College</label>
    <select name="coll5">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="c6">
    <label for="type6">College Type</label>
    <select name="type6">
      <option value="26000">Private/Out-of-State Public</option>
      <option value="10000">Public In-State</option>
      <option value="3000">Community College</option>
    </select>
    <label for="coll6">Years of College</label>
    <select name="coll6">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="c7">
    <label for="type7">College Type</label>
    <select name="type7">
      <option value="26000">Private/Out-of-State Public</option>
      <option value="10000">Public In-State</option>
      <option value="3000">Community College</option>
    </select>
    <label for="coll7">Years of College</label>
    <select name="coll7">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="c8">
    <label for="type8">College Type</label>
    <select name="type8">
      <option value="26000">Private/Out-of-State Public</option>
      <option value="10000">Public In-State</option>
      <option value="3000">Community College</option>
    </select>
    <label for="coll8">Years of College</label>
    <select name="coll8">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="c9">
    <label for="type9">College Type</label>
    <select name="type9">
      <option value="26000">Private/Out-of-State Public</option>
      <option value="10000">Public In-State</option>
      <option value="3000">Community College</option>
    </select>
    <label for="coll9">Years of College</label>
    <select name="coll9">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div id="c10">
    <label for="type10">College Type</label>
    <select name="type10">
      <option value="26000">Private/Out-of-State Public</option>
      <option value="10000">Public In-State</option>
      <option value="3000">Community College</option>
    </select>
    <label for="coll10">Years of College</label>
    <select name="coll10">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

What causes some selection changes to work, and others not? How can I change my JavaScript to account for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are way more efficient ways to perform this task; however, the reason this code isn't working as expected is because you aren't matching correctly your for loop variables in all cases.

For example:

```
case '5':
none = document.querySelectorAll('#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10');
for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
  none[i].style.display = 'none';
}
inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5');
for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
  inline[i].style.display = 'block';
}
break;
```

in the second for loop, you should be checking for the length of `inline`, not the length of `none`.  i.e.:

```
case '5':
none = document.querySelectorAll('#c6,#c7,#c8,#c9,#c10');
for (i = 0; i < none.length; i++) {
  none[i].style.display = 'none';
}
inline = document.querySelectorAll('#c1,#c2,#c3,#c4,#c5');
for (i = 0; i < inline.length; i++) {
  inline[i].style.display = 'block';
}
break;
```

This mistake is repeated multiple times throughout your code.